# Unable to log into Windows XP Pro Domain Not Available

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts, domain, administrator, windows-domain

Trying to access an old laptop I have but at the windows login screen I attempt to log in and get the message "Unable to log in because <Domain Name> is unavailable".

This laptop is not on a domain or a network and I do not know the computer name.

I have blanked the passwords of the local administrator and user account using Offline NT Password and Registry Editor but still unable to log in?

Any advice would be grateful or if you can point me to the registry location I can edit or delete to remove the domain.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unplugged the computer from any sort of network. Then reboot the system. After it reboots, try logging in to any given user with the last password that was used successfully on that account. Probably want a user that has admin access so that you remove the domain settings. *Note: This only works if the user has previously logged in to that specific system.*

Here is a easy solution to the computer name issue without logging in to any user. At the *Log On to Windows* screen, push **[ALT]+[CTRL]+[DEL]** as if you were about to attempt to log in. Then click on the **Option** button until you see third input option called *Log on to*. Once you see this, select down arrow for the **Log on to** drop down menu. In the list, there will be one option labeled with "*this computer*"  in parentheses. To the left of *this computer* is the full computer name that you seek.

#### Example Screenshot:

[image: The computer name along with the "This Computer"]

***JBOGUS-DESKTOP** is the computer name of this computer.*

Answer (score 0):

I had to re-install XP in the end (after backing up the hard disk first).

Answer (score 0):

Unplugged the computer from any sort of network. Then reboot the system. After it reboots, try logging in to any given user with the last password that was used successfully on that account. Probably want a user that has admin access so that you remove the domain settings. Note: This only works if the user has previously logged in to that specific system.

Here is a easy solution to the computer name issue without logging in to any user. At the Log On to Windows screen, push [ALT]+[CTRL]+[DEL] as if you were about to attempt to log in. Then click on the Option button until you see third input option called Log on to. Once you see this, select down arrow for the Log on to drop down menu. In the list, there will be one option labeled with "this computer" in parentheses. To the left of this computer is the full computer name that you seek.

Example Screenshot:

Unplugged the computer from any sort of network. Then reboot the system. After it reboots, try logging in to any given user with the last password that was used successfully on that account. Probably want a user that has admin access so that you remove the domain settings. Note: This only works if the user has previously logged in to that specific system.

Here is a easy solution to the computer name issue without logging in to any user. At the Log On to Windows screen, push [ALT]+[CTRL]+[DEL] as if you were about to attempt to log in. Then click on the Option button until you see third input option called Log on to. Once you see this, select down arrow for the Log on to drop down menu. In the list, there will be one option labeled with "this computer" in parentheses. To the left of this computer is the full computer name that you seek.

Example

- Screenshot

:

- List item

[**

- enter link description here

---

**]1

Comment: Why do you duplicate answer?